# "Too many of your edits were rejected" message is not integrated into the page

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rate-limiting

Whenever a user receives a `Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.` message, it seems like it is a PHP `die()` message, and it looks ugly when it isn't integrated into the normal page. Is it possible to integrate it into the normal Stack Exchange window, rather than be on a page with nothing else on it?

Comment: +1 for having the courage to mention that this has happened to you.

Comment: can you edit again ?, I´ve been baned for 5 days...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible, yes.

Likely to happen, no.

Our intention with the block is to stop people who perform unacceptable edits from editing. This is a huge edge case and we do not expect it to happen in the majority of cases. If you somehow slipped the threshold, you already wasted a huge amount of time for a **large amount** of **very high rep** users, you should not be rewarded for that.

That said:

1. I am not against adjusting thresholds, they are a bit harsh at the moment especially when it comes to tag wiki editing.
2. I am not against linking to a blog post explaining what makes a **great edit** so you can learn how to correct your ways.

Comment: When has this feature been implemented? Can't find it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446)

Comment: *If* there's an overview of all proposed edits from a user, and *if* that's a bit hidden, then maybe link to that as well?

Comment: @Shadow, it's noted on [How does peer review for edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work) since February 1st: *There are strict limits enforced. If a user (anonymous or registered) submits many rejected edits they will be automatically banned from suggesting edits. The fixed size queue also helps protect us from abuse.* I'd say it has been in place since day 1.

Comment: Thanks @Arjan didn't see that one before..

Comment: @Arjan ... hard to find ... but yes http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/27955

Comment: Sorry, @waffles, I meant an overview for the user, to be added to the links of your second list item. (I can see such list at the bottom of that specific suggested edit, but I guess there's not some other list for each user? No need for that, of course, unless it already exists somewhere.)

Comment: @Waffles, maybe a user's suggested edits are already listed on the "Review" tab in the activity, the same list that shows "accepted/rejected" for the reviewers?

Comment: With the current thresholds for tag wiki editing, and keeping in mind that summary+main wiki edits are counted separately, it only takes _three_ rejected edits to get this message. So I think "huge amount of time" is an overstatement.